# Confirmatory Factor Analysis factor loading cut off threshold

Tags: confirmatory-factor, threshold

To conduct Confirmatory Factor Analysis (CFA), what is the usual cut off threshold for items' factor loading on their factors?

I have found justifications for a more conventional .40 or a more stringent .60 as cut off for Exploratory Factor Analysis, but not sure if these justification can be used on CFA?

If I used a more stringent .60 as cut off for CFA, are there justifications I can use?

Thanks!